# Windows phone 8 application compatibility

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developping application using windows phone 8 sdk and I wonder if this application can work on device that use windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Yes, it can work on wp8.1 device very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows Phone 8 app can continue to run on Windows Phone version 8.1.

But there are some compatibility and breaking changes you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642084%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. The feature that i look for is the possibility to use the OpenFilePicker and I thank that it exists in windows phone 8.1 sdk